# How to use the proper version of MySQL with docker?

Tags: mysql, docker, virtualization

I am a beginner to Docker. That said, I noted the following which I think is kind of weird.

After executed a `docker pull mysql/mysql-server:5.6.23` in console and after I played a little bit with Docker and his getting started tutorial, I started the pulled MySQL v5.6.23 (don't ask me why such an old version) container and I realized that the welcome message was showing the wrong version of MySQL:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.6.24 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
(...)
```

Still playing with docker commands, I discovered the following:

```
$ docker container inspect bde088053099
(...)
         "Config": {
            "Hostname": "bde088053099",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PACKAGE_URL=https://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/docker/x86_64/mysql-community-server-minimal-5.6.24-2.el7.x86_64.rpm"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mysqld"
            ],
            "Image": "mysql/mysql-server:5.6.23",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
(...)
```

The package url is pointing to the next subversion of MySQL instead of the one I am aiming to:
`"PACKAGE_URL=https://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/docker/x86_64/mysql-community-server-minimal-5.6.24-2.el7.x86_64.rpm"` though the image name contains the right version number `"Image": "mysql/mysql-server:5.6.23"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, YES, this issue could be reproduced, but with [mysql/mysql-server:5.6.23](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server), not [mysql:5.6.23](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql). Your description in your post is conflict, please double check.

**Next**, I think there should be `build script` issue in oracle team at the period of 5 years ago when doing `5.6x` release (E.g. `5.6.24` also not ok), as other version is ok.

So, if you insist to use `5.6.23`, I suggest you switch to `docker pull mysql:5.6.23` which is ok (NOTE: **not** `docker pull mysql/mysql-server:5.6.23`):

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -it mysql:5.6.23 
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

**Finally**, the difference of above 2 docker hub repo links:

They are all official image, just `mysql:5.6.23` based on debian, while `mysql/mysql-server:5.6.23` based on oracle linux.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I pulled ` mysql/mysql-server:5.6.23`, I'll fix it. Tomorrow (UTC-5) I will try your solution and mark it as Accepted if it is the case.